# Difference between "dimenticare" and "non ricordare"

Tags: difference

Both of them have the same idea of no to remember or to forget. So what is the difference between those two?

Comment: Tia27, first of all, please demonstrate that you at least looked up these words in a dictionary and know about all their possible meanings. Second, right now you don't ask about two words, both of which mean "to forget" or "not to remember". You ask about one word in affirmative sense and another in negative sense, so that the whole difference would be defined by the meanings of "dimenticare" and "ricordare".

Comment: "Ricordare" is something that has gone out of your heart while "dimenticare" in someting that has gone out of your mind; infact the first is related to "cuore" and the second to "mente"

Comment: there are at least two differences. (1) Whenever you find "non ricordo" (presente) you may use "ho dimenticato" (passato prossimo), and the same happens with "non ricordavo" / "avevo dimenticato". (imperfetto/trapassato prossimo) Thus, "dimenticare" is an action set in the past, unlike "ricordare". (2) "dimenticare" may refer to a voluntary action (*ho dimenticato quello che mi hai fatto*), while "non ricordare" is never voluntary.